# Probability that a random edge coloring of the complete graph is proper

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

This is a repost of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458780/probability-that-a-random-edge-coloring-of-the-complete-graph-is-proper) math.se question that I am posting here since it received no attention there.

> What is the probability that a random edge coloring of $K_n$ with 
>   $m \geq n$ colors results in a proper coloring ?

By random edge coloring I mean that every edge is assigned a color from $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ uniformly at random.

If we define the event $E_i$ to mean that edge $e_i$ is not incident with an edge of the same color class of the event $V_i$ that vertex $v_i$ is incident with edges of distinct colors, then it is easy to get a bound for the above probabiity in terms of $Pr[E_i]$ or $Pr[V_i]$ by using the union bound.

The problem is that it appears that such approach only gives bounds that make sense only when $m = \mathcal(n^2)$ which is not interesting.

Hence I am wondering if there is a more sensitive way to bound/compute the above probability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p(n)$ be this probability.  Now consider you coloured $K_{n-1}$ successfully and add one new vertex.  As the edges from the new vertex is coloured, there are simple bounds on how many colours are available.  I get that the $i$-th new edge ($i$ starting at 0) has between $m-n+2-i$ and $m-n+2$ colours available.  Therefore
$$ \frac {(m-n+2)!}{m^{n-1} (m-2n+3)!} \le \frac{p(n)}{p(n-1)} \le \frac{(m-n+2)^{n-1}}{m^{n-1}}.$$
Multiply these ratios together to bound $p(n)$. The left bound starts to bite when $m\ge 2n-3$, the right bound earlier.

I'm sure this can be improved.

Comment: Hm.. I am not able to obtain a constant lower bound for $p(n)$ from these bounds. Is it possible to do so? If not, can this be improved so that $O(n)$ edges guarantee that a random edge-coloring is proper with a probability of (say ) at least 1/2?

Comment: @Jernej: I don't understand "O(n) edges".  Do you mean colours?

Comment: Err - yes yes, colors!

Comment: @Jerneq: You need $\Omega(n^2)$ colours just to have $\Omega(1)$ probability that the colours at a single vertex are distinct.  This is the birthday paradox.